# How to check if a value is included between two other values?

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements

I'm trying to express a condition like this:

```
if 33.75 < degree <= 56.25
  # some code
end
```

But Ruby gives this error:

```
undefined method `<=' for true:TrueClass
```

I'm guessing that one way to do it is something like:

```
if 33.75 < degree and degree <= 56.25
  # code
end
```

But there is no another, easier way?

Comment: Another solution would be to use an interval: `(33.75..56.25).include?(degree)`

Comment: This is typical of virtually every programming language with only a few exceptions. This is because most languages have either unary or binary operators. Remember that `33.75 < degree` evaluates to either `true` or `false` and `true <= 56.25` is not a valid comparison.

Comment: So I would better use &&. (Thanks toro2k for fixing my bad english ;))

Comment: `if 33.75 < degree and degree <= 56.25` is close to the traditional way we'd do it in other languages. I'd recommend using parenthesis to avoid any order-of-precedence issues, as those can vary: `if ((33.75 < degree) and (degree <= 56.25))`. Also some languages would prefer/recommend using `&&` instead of `and`. This form works in languages that don't support ranges or have methods such as `between` or `includes`.

Comment: Using natural language words (that are concise enough) are easier to read than symbols. Ada is beautiful. Perl is ugly.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Ruby also has between?:

```
if value.between?(lower, higher)
```

Comment: This should be the selected answer. This is exactly what `between?` was coded for, and I believe the performance will be higher (even though I didn't benchmarked it to see)

Comment: Hi fotanus, you are right. It seems that between? is made for this situations but unfortunately it doesn't fit exactly to what I need. In the lower limit I need a < instead of <=

Comment: be aware this will include both, lower and upper limit. `2.between(2,4)` evaluates `true` as well as `4.between(2,4)`.

Answer (score 13):

There are many ways of doing the same things in Ruby.
You can check if value is in the range by use of following methods,

`14.between?(10,20) # true`

`(10..20).member?(14) # true`

`(10..20).include?(14) # true`

But, I would suggest using `between` than `member?` or `include?`. You can find more about it [here](https://rubyinrails.com/2013/09/03/how-to-check-if-value-is-included-in-between-the-range/).

Comment: Although the link goes to "Ruby in Rails", this is actually a Ruby method, not Rails.

Answer (score 7):

You can express `a <= x <= b` as `(a..b).include? x` and `a <= x < b` as `(a...b).include? x`.

```
>> (33.75..56.25).include? 33.9
=> true
>> (33.75..56.25).include? 56.25
=> true
>>
>> (33.75..56.25).include? 56.55
=> false
```

Unfortunately, there seems no such thing for `a < x <= b`, `a < x < b`, ..

**UPDATE**

You can accomplish using `(-56.25...-33.75).include? -degree`. But it's hard to read. So I recommend you to use `33.75 < degree and degree <= 56.25`.

Comment: So my only possibility is setting the lower limit to 33.76 and use (33.76..56.25).include?(degree)...

Comment: You can use `(-56.25...-33.75).include? -degree`. But it's hard to read. I recommend you to use plain `33.75 < degree and degree <= 56.25`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I have a better understanding of comparisons in Ruby/Rails.

Comment: You are criticizing other answers for providing closed intervals, but your answer is not much different. Afterall, you are not able to provide exactly what the OP wanted just like the other answers didn't (the only, slight difference is that you mentioned it). Boomerang.

Comment: @sawa, I'm sorry, but it was not meant for criticism.

Answer (score 2):

use `between?` is the easiest way, I found most answers here didn't mention (ruby doc explanation is hard to understand too), using `between?` does INCLUDE the `min` and `max` value.

for example:

```
irb(main):001:0> 2.between?(1, 3)
=> true
irb(main):002:0> 3.between?(1, 3)
=> true
irb(main):003:0> 1.between?(1, 3)
=> true
irb(main):004:0> 0.between?(1, 3)
=> false
```

by the way, ruby doc quote:

> between?(min, max) → true or false Returns false if obj <=> min is
>   less than zero or if anObject <=> max is greater than zero, true
>   otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

```
  undefined method `<=' for true:TrueClass
```

means that Ruby is not parsing your if-condition the way you expect it.

Using `&&` and adding parentheses helps!

```
 if (33.75<degree) && (degree<=56.25)
   ...
 end
```

It's a bad habit to leave out parentheses -- as soon as the expression gets more difficult, you could get a surprising outcome. I've seen this many times in other people's code.

Using `and` instead of `&&` in Ruby is a **very bad** idea, see:

https://www.tinfoilsecurity.com/blog/ruby-demystified-and-vs

http://rubyinrails.com/2014/01/30/difference-between-and-and-in-ruby/

Comment: The OP already provided that idea, without parentheses, and it works. You just added unnecessary parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this notation:

```
(1..5) === 3           # => true
(1..5) === 6           # => false
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust value to range?

```
value = 99 
[[value,0].max, 5].min # 5

value = -99
[[value,0].max, 5].min # 0

value = 3
[[value,0].max, 5].min # 3
```